# Pass parameters to a SOAP Service

Tags: orbeon

I can't figure out how to pass parameters coming from a form to a web service. I suppose i have to use an XPATH expression but i don't know how and where.

Is there somebody here that knows how to do that ?

In advance thank you,

Comment: Could you please comment here and tell us more about where that parameter comes from? Is it coming from a form field? You tagged this question "orbeon"; are you using Form Builder?

Comment: Yes, i' have created a form in Orbeon with the Form Builder.

Comment: I want when a form field has been changed to send the value of this form field to another system.   There is no problem to catch the change event with an action. My problem is  i can't see how to retrieve the value from the form field.

Comment: Got it; you can do this with Form Builder, without having to write any code. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this how-to: [Call a service passing a field value](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/how-to/fb-fr/call-service). It will walk you though the process of creating a form which uses the [Yahoo! Weather API](http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/) to give you weather information about a city you select, calling the service every time you change the value, and showing the result in another field.

[image: Screenshot showing form]